# Firebase push notifications - node worker

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, firebase

I need to send iOS push notifications to user whenever a certain child is added to a Firebase path.

I was thinking, that the best way to do that, would be to make a Node.js worker on Heroku, that would listen for changes and send a notification using Urban Airship.

I'm not sure what the best way is to listen for changes on Firebase from a Node.js worker on Heroku is. I'm not that familiar with heroku workers and Node.js.

Can anyone give me some pointers? Examples?

Comment: How about a queue system: push notification objects to a location that's watched by the server, and use transactions to process then remove them. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue for a sample implementation.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into it.

Comment: Here is a relevant question I thought was cool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617476/how-to-mitigate-against-long-startup-times-in-firebase-workers-when-dataset-gets

Answer (score 4):

Sending push notifications with Firebase and node-apn is easy:

```
var apn = require("apn");
var Firebase = require("firebase");

// true for production pipeline
var service = new apn.connection({ production: false }); 

// Create a reference to the push notification queue
var pushRef = new Firebase("<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/notificationQueue");
// listen for items added to the queue
pushRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

    // This location expects a JSON object of:
    // {
    //     "token": String - A user's device token
    //     "message": String - The message to send to the user
    // }
    var notificationData = snapshot.val();
    sendNotification(notificationData);
    snapshot.ref().remove();

});

function sendNotification(notificationData) {
    var notification = new apn.notification();
    // The default ping sound
    notification.sound = "ping.aiff";
    // Your custom message
    notification.alert = notificationData.message;
    // Send the notification to the specific device token
    service.pushNotification(notification, [notificationData.token]);
    // Clean up the connection
    service.shutdown();
}
```

For hosting this script, you won't be able to use a PaaS like Heroku. They tend to kill idle sockets. Instead you'll have to use a virtual machine.

[Google Cloud Platform has a Node.js launcher that works well.](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/nodejs?q=node)

Comment: from the line: `"<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/notificationQueue"`, what is the "`notifiationQueue`", or is that just the reference to listen for changes in Firebase?  Also on your second note, referncing: "Google Cloud Platform has a Node.js launcher that works well.", why not use Firebase hosting?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's how you listen to when push notifications need to be sent to the specific device.

2. Firebase Hosting is for static assets only, so no server processes.

Comment: ok, then this will solve my problem. I was following the tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio and using servlets in app engine, but it was not listening to firebase node in real-time as the app engine socket kept closing...., and it could only be scheduled given the `cron.xml` file. Very disappointing...

Comment: Will using node.js solve the problem I outlined above? I had the question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643730/how-to-keep-app-engine-servlet-listening-to-firebase

Comment: Lastly, is your example aligned for non-blocking?

Comment: That would send notifications every time your server restarts (for god knows what reason) or when you start the first time it would send a notification for each existing message.