# How to keep App Engine Servlet Listening to Firebase

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase

I am following the tutorial at: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

I have everything working and the email is sending every 2 minutes as it should. However, I now wish to extend this to trigger sending an email only upon data change on the Firebase node, **not** sending a message every 2 minutes.

To test I replaced the `cron.xml` file 
from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
   <cron>
       <url>/hello</url>
       <description>Send me an email of outstanding items in the morning</description>
       <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
   </cron>
</cronentries>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries/>
```

To clear out the scheduled tasks.

But now upon making a change in the Firebase db, the email is never sent....

*How can I keep my app engine server "listening" to the firebase node and subsequently produce an action given `onDataChanged` in real-time?*

MyServlet class:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("com.example.username.myapplication.backend.MyServlet");

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        Log.info("Got cron message, constructing email.");

        //Create a new Firebase instance and subscribe on child events.
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase("[firebase ref]");
        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Build the email message contents using every field from Firebase.
                final StringBuilder newItemMessage = new StringBuilder();
                newItemMessage.append("This should arrive very closely after changing the data");


                //Now Send the email
                Properties props = new Properties();
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                try {
                    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                    //Make sure you substitute your project-id in the email From field
                    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("anything@[app-engine].appspotmail.com",
                            "Todo Nagger"));
                    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            new InternetAddress("myEmail@gmail.com", "Recipient"));
                    msg.setSubject("Feast Email Test");
                    msg.setText(newItemMessage.toString());
                    Transport.send(msg);
                } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.warning(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Or should I just use node.js...?

Comment: You mentioned the tutorial already, but this error almost always occurs when auto scaling is enabled (covered in the tut). See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/app$20engine/firebase-talk/CZYPteFV1Xw/BZ_DooKlDAAJ).

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to log the onCancelled() handler to see if your listener is being rejected.

Comment: @Kato, I followed the tutorial exactly, copying and pasting the entirety of the `appengine.web.xml` file....I will just use node.js, this is took much overhead for such a simply test...

Comment: @Kato, update, I migrated to node.js, and there are no problems with the real-time functionality in listening to Firebase for updates, then triggering an action. Thank you

Comment: Heymy poc is not working yet.  Change [YOUR-CLOUD-PROJECT-ID] to your Cloud Platform Console project ID. How to create a project is described in Prerequisites.     Here what is the cloud project id.

Comment: @Sauron is there anyway you could help me ; I'm struggling on how to deploy a node.js server-side implementation on app engine to observe my firebase database; how did you go about it?

Comment: @theeben my apologies for the short answer, but I simply followed the documentation for deploying node.js to app engine

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I give it a shot again. I'm new to node.js and its just not quite a clear picture yet specially the role of html in it when in this case, all is required is a background servlet type of job to observe the Firebase. eventually I intent to implement Firebase queue on app engine which would handle the tasks ; say to sanitize chat content, etc ..

Answer (score 3):

Your question is actually a question about AppEngine and how to create a Servlet that starts automatically and automatically performs some initialization.

You will want to keep manual scaling on, but follow the steps here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#using_a_load-on-startup_servlet

for setting up your listeners on init() instead of an http request.
What you are trying is definitely possible and have seen it run elsewhere.

Comment: But overall in terms of scaling, is this not easier with node.js...?

Comment: Firebase even explicitly provides explicit documentation for node:https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html

Comment: Sure nodejs is an option.  AppEngine is more of a PaaS that ensures your service is running.  You do not need to provision instances or clusters or worry about restarts.

Comment: But for my use case, ie. basically a listener when a Firebase node is updated, will then trigger an action to send an email or push notification...is node.js the best to use in terms of development speed and scaling?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is you can't do that yet. 
Google cloud endpoints have a timeout of 1 min.  Cron jobs also have a timeout.

What you need is triggers. This feature was demoed at Google io 16. Whenever data changes, a rest request is fired from firebase to a server and path of your choice.

Even I am waiting for this to arrive soon.