# Is App-Engine suitable as a backend listener to Firebase Data Base for real time event handling

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry if that has been answered - I couldn't find a complete answer - as there seems to be conflicting resources.

What I'm trying to achieve is the architecture where my backend 'communicates' in real time with millions of clients through Firebase DB (RTD or FS). Kind of like what's drawn here: [image]

The architecture in a nutshell: millions of clients write 'events' to the Firebase DB, my java server listens to these 'events', processes them and writes 'responses' to the Firebase DB that are synced back to the clients.

The question: Is App Engine the best solution? Is it even suitable for the job?

On the one hand, in App Engine's documentation there's an example of it used that way:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible

On the other hand, there are (seemingly) known issues with that approach:

1) App Engine instances awake on http requests, not on firebase events. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357458/1806956
Jobs have a timeout, so even if we do a cron wakeup every minute, it doesn't ensure (or does it?) that the listener will keep living forever.

2) App Engine does not support the Firebase Admin SDK due to background threads? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046605/1806956

3) App Engine limits the number of background threads. In a real app, we're talking about potential thousands of concurrent users, all throwing events...

Are the above issues not updated? Thank you...

Comment: A little more clarification... Is the GAE responding to an event from the database or is it generating the events itself?

Comment: @jamesPoag thanks, events are generated by the million clients, I've edited the question to clarify that point.

Comment: Have you looked into [Firebase Cloud function database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)? Watch the video on that page.